# An object with two properties. One with an initial value, and the second with a function which changes it

Tags: javascript, function, object

Create an object called `chameleon` with two properties:

1. `color`, whose value is initially set to 'green' or 'pink'
2. `changeColor`, a function which changes `chameleon`'s `color` to 'pink'
   if it is 'green', or to 'green' if it is 'pink'

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
const chameleon = {
    color: 'pink',
    function changeColor() {
        chameleon.color = 'green';
    }
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I'm sure it's something simple for most of you, but I am a beginner and cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Your don't need `function` in front of `changeColor()` as you're creating it in an object. Your function also isn't implementing the logic to switch between pink/green. You're also not closing your object with a final `};` on the last line

Comment: OMG! Such a simple fix! All I had to do was do just as you said and put the }; back in and get rid of the function and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: chameleon should produce the expected result when “changeColor()” is invoked

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class:

```
class Chameleon{
     constructor(color){
          this.color = color;
     }
     changeColor(){
           if (this.color == "green"){
               this.color = "pink";
           } else {
               this.color = "green";
           }
     }
 }

 var c = new Chameleon("green");
 console.log(c);
 c.changeColor();
 console.log(c);
```

Comment: Oh, great! That's something I have yet to learn, but I am excited about getting there!

Answer (score 0):

```
const chameleon = {
    color: 'green',
    changeColor: function () {
        if(this.color === 'pink') {
            this.color = 'green';
        }
        else {
            this.color = 'pink';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).